# In Powershell how can I create a HashSet with the constructor accepting a collection?

Tags: powershell, hashset

I want to create a `HashSet` using [the constructor accepting a collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_HashSet_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__)

But none of my attempts are successful:

```
C:\> $c = @(1,2,3,4,5)
C:\> New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]
C:\> New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int] -ArgumentList @(,$c)
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "HashSet`1" and the argument count: "1".
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int] -ArgumentList @(,$ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

C:\> New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int] -ArgumentList $c
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "HashSet`1" and the argument count: "5".
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int] -ArgumentList $c
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

C:\> New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int] -ArgumentList @($c)
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "HashSet`1" and the argument count: "5".
At line:1 char:1
+ New-Object System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int] -ArgumentList @($c ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

C:\>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: have you tried to see if there is a `.Add()` method? when i make a $Var for that type thus ... `$Test = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::new()`, there is a `.Add()` method on that $Var - - thus ... `$Test.Add()`.

Comment: doesn't seem there is constructor to add array. You can do something like @(1,2,3,4,5) | foreach {$hs.add($_)}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been fiddling with this and it seems this works:

```
[int[]]$c = 1,2,3,4,5
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::new([System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[int]]$c)
```

You can even leave out the `[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable[int]]` part here and just do

```
[int[]]$c = 1,2,3,4,5
[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::new($c)
```

**Without** declaring the array as `[int[]]` it does not work and you'll get the error

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]"
>   to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32]".

**With** the typecast `[int[]]`, the type for variable `c$` is `System.Int32[]` and not simply `System.Object[]` and that is exactly what the constructor wants.

Hope that helps

Comment: Note that you can just get away with `[int[]]$c = 1,2,3,4,5` or `$c = 1,2,3,4,5` followed by `[System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[int]]::new([int[]]$c)`. The same is true if you call `HashSet.UnionWith()` on an existing HashSet on a collection. Powershell seems to coerce any collection to an `[Object[]]` when passed in this way unless you explicitly coerce it back.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a little old, but you can just cast a list to a set

```bsh
> $fileTypes = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]] @(".jpg", ".txt", ".log", ".ini")
> $fileTypes
.jpg
.txt
.log
.ini
> $fileTypes.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     HashSet`1                                System.Object

> $fileTypes.Contains(".ini")
True
```

Answer (score -2):

apparently you cannot add the entire collection to the HashSet as such. [*frown*] you need to iterate over the collection and use the `.Add()` method. if you add a collection *directly*, you get that entire collection as *one* item in the set. ouch!

so you need something like this ...

```
$HashSetTest = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new()
$FileExtList = (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -File).Extension

$FileExtList.Where({$_}).ForEach({[void]$HashSetTest.Add($_)})

$HashSetTest.GetType()
'=' * 40
$HashSetTest.Count
'=' * 40
$HashSetTest
'=' * 40
```

output ...

```
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     HashSet`1                                System.Object
========================================
10
========================================
.csv
.zip
.txt
.json
.log
.ini
.tmp
.bmp
.js
.ani
========================================
```

Comment: So, what result would you have, if you do `$HashSetTest = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new( [string[]] (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $env:TEMP -File).Extension )`?

Comment: it works. [*grin*] i get one blank entry caused by a no-extension file in my temp dir, but that is why i put in the `.Where({$_})` test. however, i see no reason to build the HashSet without assigning it to a $Var, so my 3-step method seems more obvious to me.

Comment: Well, OP does not ask, how to build `HashSet`. OP ask, how to use specific `HashSet`'s constructor from PowerShell. And your answer looks like you are answering, that it is impossible thing to do.

Comment: @PetSerAl - the exact method the OP seeks does not appear to work. so the OP is recommended to choose one that _does_ work. [*grin*] you have shown one that is pretty nifty, i've shown another variant that also appears to do the needed thing - put a collection into a hashset. two solutions for the OP to pick from! [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you *can* add an entire collection to a hash set. The key (no pun intended) is to declare the collection as an array as Theo mentioned
`[string[]]$validQueries = @("searchtext", "path");`
`$queryArgs = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[String]]::new($validQueries,[StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase)`